# How can I refactor this method to be more idiomatic to Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a method in a class:

```js
  public get selectedExpansion(): number {
    let selection = localStorage.getItem(ConsolidateStacks.SELECTION_KEY);
    if (selection == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return +selection;
  }
```

Is there a way I can simplify/refactor this logic to be more typescript-like? In this case, I think it should mean no more than 1-2 lines of code. Like for example, if it's valid to use `+` on a null number, I could do this:

```
return +localStorage.getItem(ConsolidateStacks.SELECTION_KEY);
```

But in my testing this does not work, I get errors.

I also thought of using what I thought was ternary, but somehow it converts `null` to a string, like `"null"`:

```
return selection ? +selection : null;
```

Note I am using Typescript 3.5. I believe the `?.` operator is in 3.7, which would be nice to have, but assume for this question I cannot change my version of Typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually returns `number | null`.

```
public get selectedExpansion(): number | null {
    const selection = localStorage.getItem(ConsolidateStacks.SELECTION_KEY) 
    return selection ? parseInt(selection, 10) : null
}
```

`+null` returns 0, so that won't work.

Comment: My understanding is that all types are nullable in Typescript. So the `| null` is superfluous. Please correct me if I'm wrong. What I had seems to run just fine. Also how is your return statement different/better than what I had in my OP? e.g. `return selection ? +selection : null;`

Comment: Nullable and non-nullable types are explicit, because they need different handling. If your selection is zero-based, for example, `null + 10 = 10`. "No selection" is not the same as "selecting the first item". Apart from the type signature, `parseInt` is better because `parseInt` is Web Scale. `+selection` is from the JS Ghetto, but by all means - code like a Gangsta!

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. How is it that my code works fine without `| null` on the return type?

Comment: Your code works fine, except that no code calling it will warn you in the IDE that it may return `null` at run-time instead of a number. So there are possible scenarios where you get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my last question is: Under what conditions (at the call site) will the IDE warn that it will return null? I could see the IDE assuming that it can be nullable at all times, because language semantics define it that way.

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKYBtXVQEwKIAeADgIZjLxgAUA1qgJ4BcKUATjGAOYCUzYIAWwBGqVogA+ifunSIA3gFgAUIlWIICZFBQYssBIgC8idHAgl0AZShxWJTqgB0DqAEkoqAbQbdEytYisqFAgrEhomNCUiAD8iKSsaK5gUFQRepQANIgAjAAMvnwgMsoAvsrKGuTa6dg4RjqRHvjEZBQIVADkyHACwQAWHJydvgDUiADMykA)